# Why is my circle emitting light at a funny angle?

Tags: normals, reflection, emission

You can see from the reflection that the light coming from my 'sun' is not in line with the normal of the shape. Instead it comes off to the left at an angle? Any ideas why this might be?

I have checked that the normal definitely points to the camera in my scene, so I'd assume the reflection should do the same...

Any help greatly appreciated! [image: emittion at strange angle]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! There was some bump on the plane that seemed to be interfering with the emission :)